# using abp to generation code ,include controller and view

Tags: code-generation, asp.net-boilerplate

I wanna using abp to generating code ,The follow is my setup.
1.select database table field.(field type,like text password or dropdownlist)
2.set search option 
3.generation code(include CURD and view.html)
How do I to do it?and how to generation code,using T4 template?

Comment: mark!.....................

Comment: currently there is no solution for this!